# Collection update optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, spring-data-jpa

For example we have collection stored objects in DB (simplified to String for example):

```
Collection<String> existed = someRepository.findElements(); //returns "A", "B", "B", "C"
```

We have a new collection that must replace old data:

```
Collection<String> received = Arrays.asList("B", "C", "C" ,"D");
```

The first idea was to remove all previous data from DB and save all from `received` collection like:

```
someRepository.removeAll(existed);
someRepository.saveAll(received);
```

But in case of lot's of common elements, it will cause surplus data transfer between application and DB.

On other hand we can find elements what to remove, to add, but it requires a lot of `equals` method calling and it will be slower to check all the items in memory, and IMHO its not good.

The mostly liken expected result is:

- "A", second "B" will be in toRemove collection (that we call for `removeAll`)
- one "C", "D" will be in toAdd collection (that we call for `saveAll`)
- common "B" and "C" will not be touched

So do you have any solution to resolve such cases more optimized?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a map or (better) a LinkedHashSet<String> for "existed"? Each key can only be present once, so you don't have to search duplicates.

Comment: @Calaf Sure, but we need to remove duplicates from db too. For hibernate those objects are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found utilities from Apache Commons:

```
Collection intersection = CollectionUtils.intersection(existed, received); //intersection between 2 collections

Collection toRemove = CollectionUtils.disjunction(existed, intersection); //getting disjunction between existed and intersection
Collection toAdd = CollectionUtils.disjunction(received, intersection); //getting disjunction between received and intersection
```